# IllegalArgumentException adding a window to a container.

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities

I am new to Java swing. I do have a problem when invoking my Jframe from main class. It may be a duplicate but I cant find out why my code is not worked. So I am posting here.

Mainclass

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SendMail sendMail = new SendMail();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();                                
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(sendMail,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

JFrame

```
public class SendMail extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form SendMail
 */
public SendMail() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jFileChooser1 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    jFileChooser2 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    to = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    toLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    toCc = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    toBcc = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cc = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    bcc = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    sendButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    fileName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    attach = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    to.setText("TO");
    to.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            toActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    toLabel.setText("TO  ");

    toCc.setText("CC");

    toBcc.setText("BCC");

    cc.setText("CC");
    cc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ccActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    bcc.setText("BCC");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(toBcc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 142, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(toCc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(toLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(to)
                .addComponent(cc)
                .addComponent(bcc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 199, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(to, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(toLabel))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(toCc)
                .addComponent(cc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(toBcc)
                .addComponent(bcc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    sendButton.setText("Send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sendButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    attach.setText("Attach");
    attach.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            attachActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 244, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(sendButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(fileName)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(attach, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 197, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(fileName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(attach))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(sendButton))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"It may be a duplicate but I cant find out why my code is not worked."* Link to 3 of the duplicates you found. .. You did *look,* right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch

```
public class SendMail extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

to

```
public class SendMail extends javax.swing.JPanel
```

You cannot add one JFrame to another.

Comment: And if you want it as an new window, extend JDialog instead